# Stuck with how permutation works inside a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

Can anyone help me understand what's going on in this function? This code is from the book **Learning Python 5th Edition*** by Mark Lutz, Chapter 20, Comprehensions and Generations, '*Permutations: All possible combinations'*...

```
def permute1(seq):
    if not seq:
        return [seq]
    else:
        res = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            for x in permute1(rest):
                res.append(seq[i:i+1]+x)
        return res
```

It's supposed to generate all possible permutations from a sequence. The author explained what it does, but refused to explain what goes on under the hood. I tried to print the 'rest' and 'seq[i:i+1]+x' in hopes of tracing their outputs. But I'm still confused as to how the each permutation is generated.

Comment: I think that on line 8 of your code, you should have `for x in permute1(rest):` instead of `for x in permute1(seq):`.

Comment: in line 8, you should have `rest` instead of `seq`